# How to exclude multiple columns in Spark dataframe in Python

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I found PySpark has a method called `drop` but it seems it can only drop one column at a time. Any ideas about how to drop multiple columns at the same time?

```python
df.drop(['col1','col2'])
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-653b0465e457> in <module>()
----> 1 selectedMachineView = machineView.drop([['GpuName','GPU1_TwoPartHwID']])

/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in drop(self, col)
   1257             jdf = self._jdf.drop(col._jc)
   1258         else:
-> 1259             raise TypeError("col should be a string or a Column")
   1260         return DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx)
   1261 

TypeError: col should be a string or a Column
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Simply with `select`:

```
df.select([c for c in df.columns if c not in {'GpuName','GPU1_TwoPartHwID'}])
```

or if you really want to use `drop` then `reduce` should do the trick:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

reduce(DataFrame.drop, ['GpuName','GPU1_TwoPartHwID'], df)
```

**Note**:

(*difference in execution time*):

There should be no difference when it comes to data processing time. While these methods generate different logical plans physical plans are exactly the same.

There is a difference however when we analyze driver-side code:

- the first method makes only a single JVM call while the second one has to call JVM for each column that has to be excluded
- the first method generates logical plan which is equivalent to physical plan. In the second case it is rewritten.
- finally comprehensions are significantly faster in Python than methods like `map` or `reduce`
- **Spark 2.x+** supports multiple columns in `drop`. See [SPARK-11884](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11884) (*Drop multiple columns in the DataFrame API*) and [SPARK-12204](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12204) (*Implement drop method for DataFrame in SparkR*) for detials.

Answer (score 73):

In PySpark 2.1.0 method `drop` [supports multiple columns](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=drop#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.drop):

PySpark **2.0.2**:

```
DataFrame.drop(col)
```

PySpark **2.1.0**:

```
DataFrame.drop(*cols)
```

Example:

```
df.drop('col1', 'col2')
```

or using the `*` operator as

```
df.drop(*['col1', 'col2'])
```

Comment: I have a scenario where am using

Comment: Just to be clear, in case it isn't obvious to some folks landing here, when @Patrick writes `DataFrame.drop(*cols)` above, `cols` **is a Python list**, and [putting the star before it converts it into positional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean).

Answer (score 9):

The right way to do this is:

```py
df.drop(*['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

The `*` needs to come outside of the brackets if there are multiple columns to drop.

Comment: This doesn't add any new information to this post.The `*` unpacking is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42043699/5858851) with further explanation of the syntax in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35674490/how-to-exclude-multiple-columns-in-spark-dataframe-in-python#comment92350606_42043699)

Comment: The answer you point to does not work for me:  df.drop('col1', 'col2') is incorrect, the columns have to be in brackets and the * needs to be outside the bracket. That's why I posted.

Comment: If it's not working for you, your error is somewhere else because the `df.drop(*['col1', 'col2'])` is syntactically equivalent to `df.drop('col1', 'col2')`

Comment: @pault you're right. For some reason, your method didn't work for me earlier but now it does. In any case, the * is necessary if you do decide to use brackets, so I think it's fair to keep the answer here as a potential alternative solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Ceren: How to make this changes happened in the dataframe ? Like it does in python inplace=True, then change is reflected in the dataframe. as noticed df.drop(*cols) returns new dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

In case non of the above works for you, try this:

```
df.drop(col("col1")).drop(col("col2))
```

My spark version is 3.1.2.