# Pyspark: Select all columns except particular columns

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark

I have a large number of columns in a PySpark dataframe, say 200. I want to select all the columns except say 3-4 of the columns. How do I select this columns without having to manually type the names of all the columns I want to select?

Comment: use `drop` with columns you'd like to exclude.

Comment: `df.select([c for c in df.columns if c not in {'GpuName','GPU1_TwoPartHwID'}])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude multiple columns in Spark dataframe in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35674490/how-to-exclude-multiple-columns-in-spark-dataframe-in-python)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In the end, I settled for the following :

- [Drop](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=drop#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.drop):

  `df.drop('column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3')`
- [Select](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=drop#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.select) :

  `df.select([c for c in df.columns if c not in {'column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3'}])`

Answer (score 2):

```
df.drop(*[cols for cols in [list of columns to drop]])
```

Useful if the list to drop columns is huge. or if the list can be derived programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

### this might be helpful

```
df_cols = list(set(df.columns) - {'<col1>','<col2>',....})

df.select(df_cols).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

PySpark SQL: "SELECT * except(col6, col7, col8)"

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for and works as expected. Looks like it's [widely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413819/select-except) implemented as well. Can't believe I've never came across this.